# Escape cron job definition when exporting env variables along with xargs

Tags: bash, macos, cron, environment-variables, xargs

I'm trying to write a script that requires to export some env variables by reading the values and names from an `.env` file.

Here's an example of the `.env` file:

```
INSTANCE_PROFILE_ARN=arn:aws:iam::1234567890:instance-profile/development-west
SERVICE_NAME=reports
PIPELINE_CRON='0 0 0/6 * * ?'
```

And in the `script.sh` file I'm exporting the variables using the following code:

```
if [ -f "./.env" ]; then
  echo "** Using data from .env file **"
  export $(cat .env | xargs)
fi;
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
➜ ./script.sh
./script.sh: line 5: export: `0': not a valid identifier
./script.sh: line 5: export: `0/6': not a valid identifier
./script.sh: line 5: export: `README.md': not a valid identifier
./script.sh: line 5: export: `demo.py': not a valid identifier
./script.sh: line 5: export: `script.sh': not a valid identifier
./script.sh: line 5: export: `?': not a valid identifier
PIPELINE_CRON=0
```

I've been testing some solutions I found in other post but is not working.

Using the `-d '\n'` option will not work as I am working on macOS:

```
➜ xargs -d
xargs: illegal option -- d
usage: xargs [-0opt] [-E eofstr] [-I replstr [-R replacements] [-S replsize]]
             [-J replstr] [-L number] [-n number [-x]] [-P maxprocs]
             [-s size] [utility [argument ...]]
```

Comment: I don't think that you used exactly that .env file you posted here, because this would lead to different error messages. Your approach is broken in two ways: (1) The single quotes (in `PIPELINE_CRON='0 0 0/6 * * ?'`) would be lost during this process, but they are necessary for creating the correct variable. (2) xargs feeds to `echo` as many words as will fit into the command line, and then produces a new echo command. This means that for a sufficiently large .env file, you will possibly get an unwanted line break in the middle of a variable definition.

Comment: Please test your approach first from the commandline, by doing `xargs <.env`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I'm understanding your requirement correctly, you may want to say:

```
if [[ -f ".env" ]]; then
    echo "** Using data from .env file **"
    set -a                              # set "allexport" option
    source ".env"                       # the variables are exported
    set +a                              # reset "allexport" option
fi

# export -p                             # uncomment to see exported variables
```

Comment: that's certainly easier than my way :-)

Comment: This is what I needed, I tried the `source ".env"` initially but I didn't mention (I should have) in the question that those arguments were required for an external command I'm using at the end of the script. The variables weren't visible for the external command, now they are.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the file contains nothing but bash variable assignments:

```
envfile=.env

if [ -f "$envfile" ]; then
    . "$envfile"
    export $(
        env -i bash -c '
            :
            compgen -v
            . "$1"
            compgen -v
        ' -- "$envfile" |
        sort | uniq -u
    )
fi
```

- `env -i` invokes the command (bash) with empty environment
- `compgen -v` lists all defined variables, before and after sourcing the file
- `sort | uniq u` gives the differences - ie. the new variables
- the `:` empty command is to make bash set `PIPESTATUS` so that it will not appear in the output